# Are Vaishyas mentioned in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, caste-system, yajur-veda, vaishya

I know that Vaishya and Shudra are not mentioned in Rig-Veda but Yajurveda verse lists Shudra, so my question is:

1. Do Rig, Sama, Yajur Vedas mention it (Vaishya)?

and

2. Does Atharvaveda mention them or not?

**(note:— please give answer to the first question and then to another)**

It is not related to all castes i want to know about  Vaishaya only rest i know.

Comment: Who said they are not mentioned? Listen to and read the Purusha Suktam.

Comment: i was not saying i was asking although inspite the purush sukta which i read here is not totally the answer required i was requiring other verses which was given by rickross

Comment: Yes the 4 Varnas are mentioned in all the Vedas. Since Rickross has given the answers you can refer to those.

Comment: well well i' persnally do not believe in vaishya and shudra existed in rig-veda nothing else than pusush-sukta mentions it niether how much i remember mahabharata leaving shanti parva or anushasana parva talks about it....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Vaishya is mentioned in all the 4 Vedas, because the Purusha Sukta has the word in it. And, the Purusha Sukta is found in all the 4 Vedas.

> BrAhmano asya mukham Asit
>  BAhu rAjanyah krtah
>  Uru tad asya yad
>   **vaishyah**
>  PAdbhyAm shudro ajAyata ||
>
> His key part (or mouth) was the man of the word (BrAhmana). Into the
>   Prince (rAjanya), (referring to Kshatriyas) his arms were made. While
>   his wideness (Uru;Thighs) became the producers (Vaishya). His power of
>   movement (feet) gave birth to the man of service (Shudra).
>
> **Rig Veda 10.90.12 Or VAjasaneyi SamhitA 31.11.**

Another Mantra from Yajurveda that mentions Vaishya is the following:

> Rucham no dehi brAhmaneshu (1),
>  Rucham rAjasu nah kridhi (2)
>   Rucham **vishyeshu** shudreshu (3)
>  Mayi dehi ruchA rucham (4)
>
> ....
>
> Give lustre to our BrAhmana-s (1), Give lustre to our kingly men (2).
>   Give lustre to our **Vaishya-s** and Shudra-s (3). Give lustre to me (4).
>
> **Shukla Yajurveda 18.48**

Location of the Purusha Sukta in the different Vedas are as follows:

In Rig Veda it is 10.90, in Shukla Yajur Veda's Vajasaneya Samhita it is the 31'st Adhyaya. It is not directly found in Krishna Yajur Veda Taittiriya Samhita (KYTS), but it is in the Taittiriya Aranyaka (TA) which is in fact a continuation of KYTS. And, here it is TA 3.12. The Purusha Sukta of the Sama Veda has only 6 Mantras.

Comment: That is the type of verse i was looking for thanks @rickross.;)

Comment: It is found in Krishna Yajur Veda. It says a Shudra is not fit for sacrifice somewhere.

Comment: Yes I know that mantra but to whom are you replying? This is about Vaishya and not Shudra @SparkSunshine

Comment: In the 7.1.1 of Taittiriya Samhita the word Vaishya is found.

Comment: Ok,  in other places of KYV the word is found too. @SparkSunshine