# Were there only three Varnas in Vedic Age?

Tags: vedas, shatapatha-brahmana, brahmanas, varnashrama, taittirya-brahmana

> Satapatha Brahmana II. 1.4.11
>
> “(Uttering), ‘bhuh’, Prajapati generated this earth. (Uttering)‘bhuvah’ he generated the air, and (Uttering) ‘svah’ he generated the sky.This universe is co-extensive with these worlds. (The fire) is placed with the whole. Saying ‘bhuh’, Prajapati generated the Brahman; saying ‘bhuvah’’ he generated the Kshattra; (and saying) ‘svah’, he generated theVis. The fire is placed with the whole. (Saying) ‘bhuh’, Prajapati generatedhimself; (saying) ‘bhuvah’, he generated offspring : saying ‘svah’, he generated animals. This world is so much as self, offspring, and animals. (The fire) is placed with the whole.”

> Taittirya Brahmana III. 12.9.2
>
> “This entire (universe) has been created by Brahma. Men say that the Vaishya class was produced from ric verses. They say that the Yajur Veda is the womb from which the Kshattriya was born. The Sama Veda is the source from which the Brahmins sprang. This word the ancients declared to the ancients.”

Why are Brahmanas speaking of only three Varnas? Was there never a Sudra Varna? What's the context of these hymms?

Comment: When enumerating triads, the Shudra is included in the Vit (or Vish) i.e Vaishya. It is because they form part of the general population. You can see in the quotes above, everything is fitted into triads to correspond to the bhUr-bhuvah-svah triad. This is similar to the triad of Vedas vs 4 Vedas. When triad of Vedas is needed, Atharva is included in the Rik, because they are both metrical. Shudra varna may have started out as a sub-group within Vaishyas, where they were assistants. Even in temple priests, you find main priest and assistant priest.

Comment: Hello @RamAbloh sir. Thanks a lot for your brilliant reply as usual. Actually I was trying to tackle few people who say there were only 3 Varnas and Purusha Sukta is interpolated. I did read your's and Kiron Krishnan Ji answers. Could you please write an answer on this or elaborate your explanation in comments? How is Sudra included in Vaishya sir?? How can we say that Vaishya Varna evolved into Sudra Varna? And one more doubt, even in Gita 18.41 Krishna tries to say ब्राह्मणक्षत्रियविशां श‍ूद्राणां च Why does he keep a gap between 3 and one??

Comment: [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22741) you get a couple of Vedic mantras that mention the 4 Varnas together. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: @Rickross Ji Thankyou for the link. I did know prayers for Sudra. Even we discussed Tattireya Samhita where Sudra is unfit for few sacrifises. I have 2 doubts. Why did Brahmanas club these 2 Varnas? And Samhitas dont? Why do Vedas differentiate Arya and Sudra?That Ved KA Bhed guy used to speak all nonsence and killing stuff. I am seriously disturbed by it

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru hi, they are 2 different issues. First, those who say Purusha Suktam is interpolated, what is the timeline? I had written an answer saying it is not interpolated based on its concepts and linguistic style. It belongs properly in the 10th mandala of Rig Veda. It is not out-of-place. So it is not interpolated. As for the mention of 4 varnas, some say only that verse was inserted later. But again, there is no evidence for that. The entire suktam lists all the different things in the universe coming out of Purusha. Shudra and earth both come from the feet.

Comment: The Purusha Suktam mentions the varnas as **philosophical categories**, not as hereditary lineages. The same is seen in most instances in Vedas. I have written in detail about it [here](https://goldenreed-hiranyayavetasa.blogspot.com/2020/05/first-let-us-look-at-following-passages.html).

Comment: As regards Vaishya and Shudra, if you see their attributes, they are involved in all the worldly activities like agriculture, manufacturing, business, infrastructure, engineering, arts, crafts, etc, So that is their commonality. So it is very likely in ancient times, there was no hard and fast demarcation. "Vaishya" comes from "Vish" meaning "people". So all people who were not Brahma or Kshatra were Vaishya. But as I said before, within every category, there will be some who provide service as needed.

Comment: Since this would be most widespread in the vast majority of the population, the people that provided services became more and more organized into their own groups, and these became Shudras. Plus, the start of hereditary groups also made the segregation more strict. In later times, of course, all kinds of "sins" also made people into Shudras. This is the start of the corruption of the original system of division of labor.

Comment: As regards Gita 18.41, the verse is written in anushtup chandas, so it seems from reading that the word शूद्राणां is purposely separated. It is just enumerated in that order, and to fit the chandas pattern (8+8+8+8). But other references in Gita and later texts do show that in later times, Shudra had been degraded in status. Again this is a corruption of the original system.

Comment: @RamAbloh Thanks a lot lot sir for your wonderful reply. What sages in Mahabharata say is all men were Bramhanas and all come from Brahman so everyone can aquire knowledge. And they say that after some time, men became indulged into various acts and fell from that position. Lord Shiva,Yudhistira and Narada Muni say anyone can become Knower of Brahman and therefore attain status of Bramhin. Yajnavalkya says one should carefully learn Bramhajnana even from a Chandala
Sir thanks a lot for the wonderful replies. I have read almost all articles sir in your Blog.

Comment: @RamAbloh Sir but we see sometimes Vedas saying May I be more dear to Aryan and Sudra. They were just indicating groups as you told right? And you told many Sudras atlest in Vedic age did have access to Vedic knowledge through small sacrifises like Pakayajnas??Sir the problem with Gita 18.41 is Shankaracharya wantedly tries to justify Jati system saying first 3 are Dwijas and rest have only one birth. But you clearly wrote an answer from providing Bhasyas of previous acharyas on Yajurveda 26.2 saying Veda is open to all. Why the contradiction sir??

Comment: @RamAbloh I am doing my very best to propagate glory of Hinduism as much as I can sir. But I really need your help. Can we discuss here itself when you are free???
Please have a look at my article once sir : https://drive.google.com/file/d/18kXnWr96tCsW3xG1ehoVySg3oQKWETL9/view

Comment: @RamAbloh Sir please have little kindness on me. I am really being helpless
Sir regarding Gita 18.41 how is it Anustubh Chandas? Please see the verse " ब्राह्मणक्षत्रियविशां शूद्राणां च परन्तप |
कर्माणि प्रविभक्तानि स्वभावप्रभवैर्गुणै: 
Sir you might take just few seconds for reply but that will make my whole day and kill all my misries ..  I am humbly requesting and begging for your reply! Please reply sir and please dont be angry on me. Here  च and परन्तप are also separated. How is it Anustubh Chandas

Comment: @RamAbloh Sir just read your recent answer where you said there are some errors of Chandas rules in our scriptures. Okay but does this verse really fit into Chandas? And Shankaracharya the most recent Acharya close to the Vedic Tradition says for this verse "शूद्राणाम् असमासकरणम् एकजातित्वे सति वेदानधिकारात्" Please see this once : https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=18&field_nsutra_value=41&scsh=1&setgb=1 
Please reply sir please